# Using Xidel how to extract value from xml file

Tags: xml, xidel

In the following XML file, I would like to extract the value 300.

```
<Cube>
    <Cube time="Test">
        <data name="value">300</data>
    </Cube>
</Cube>
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
xidel 1.xml -e "css('Cube[time=Test] data[name=value]')/@value"
```

How would I extract the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the trailing `/@value`, omit it and your command should return the value `300` fine :

```
xidel 1.xml -e "css('Cube[time=Test] data[name=value]')"
```

or using equivalent XPath expression :

```
xidel 1.xml -e "/Cube/Cube[@time='Test']/data[@name='value']"
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response